# fixed div while scrolling which moves other elements in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some menu items on the right hand side of my website that are: -

- Basket Summary
- Best Sellers
- Quick Links
- etc

I want the basket summary to follow down the page as the page is scrolled, I know how to this using position: fixed, but I need it to also move the other elements out of the way otherwise it will just overlap them.

I was looking at this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKXNw/) which would do the job and works but obviously thats only on button click, I would need to adapt this to scroll via jQuery.

I have read many tutorials for floated fixed divs but they are all for one div and don't have any other divs to interact with.

Any ideas if possible and/or how to do it?

Code from js fiddle as follows: -

```
$(function() {
    $('.upButton').click(function(e){
        var $parent = $('.highlight').closest('.box');
        $parent.insertBefore($parent.prev());           

    });

    $('.downButton').click(function(e){
        var $parent = $('.highlight').closest('.box');

        $parent.insertAfter($parent.next());   
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool idea but might be tricky to code and maintain... and might look weird or cluttered to users.  Perhaps just make sure nothing's ever in the way? Most sites that use position fixed on margin items set aside some space for them.  See http://www.theverge.com/microsoft/2013/1/5/3839236/google-microsoft-ecosystem-war-a-full-history for a really nice looking example (they also remove position fixed at the top of the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?: http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/YVh4q/

essentially, whenever the window scrolls check to see if your section is in the visible area and if not, adjust accordingly:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var mover = $("#sidebar .quick-links");
  if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
      //console.log("to top");
      mover.prependTo("#sidebar");
  } else if(!isFullyInViewableArea(mover)) {
      var parent = mover.closest('.section');
      if(isBelowViewableArea(mover)) {
          //console.log("moving up");
          parent.insertBefore(parent.prev());
      } else {
          //console.log("moving down");
          parent.insertAfter(parent.next());
      }
  }
});
```

I must admit, this solution is not the best user experience, i.e. it jumps instead of scrolling smoothly. If it were me I would put the movable section as the last item in the right column and move that down the page with absolute positioning so it follows the top of the view-able area exactly.

Comment: Yes thats pretty much what I needed, but yes your right, it does jump, its fine going down but the problem is going back up as it needs to hit the bottom of the window to move.  I cant really have it at the bottom as its the cart I will be using it on which is generally at the top of the right menu all the time.  Is there anyway to make this smoother and so it doesnt need to hit the bottom to go back up?

Comment: Just to add, once it hits the top of the window it wants to stay in that position as the user scrolls.

Comment: you can do something similar to what facebook does and make the `quick-links` css `position:fixed` as soon as it becomes the last item in the column. Then, revert it back once you scroll up again. PS> since I did technically answer your question, any way I could get you to accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

[Drag & Drop](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) is best.

Greetings.

Comment: Sorry but that's nothing to do with what I need.